# How to pass Ajax POST request with GeoJSON or simply JSON data in Django view?

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, post

I am learning how to use jQuery Ajax and how to combine it with my Django project.

My Django template comes with a JS source that adds a Leaflet `EasyButton` to my map with an Ajax POST request to pass some JSON data that is then processed on the Django side:

```
// Create a button to process Geoman features
var btn_process_geoman_layers = L.easyButton('<img src="' + placeholder + '" height="24px" width="24px"/>', function (btn, map) {        
    var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    
    // Retrieve all Geoman layers
    var geoman_layers = map.pm.getGeomanLayers(true).toGeoJSON();
    // Process only layers that are feature collections
    if (geoman_layers["type"] === "FeatureCollection")
    {
        // For every feature (e.g. marker, polyline, polygon, circle)
        for (feature_idx in geoman_layers["features"])
        {
            var feature = geoman_layers["features"][feature_idx];
            
            // pass the feature using Ajax to Django
            switch(feature["geometry"]["type"])
            {
                case "Polygon":
                    console.log("Polygon");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "",
                        data: {
                            "feature": feature
                        },
                        datatype: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (res, status) {
                            //alert(res);
                            alert(status);
                        },
                        error: function (res) {
                            alert(res.status);                                                                                                                          
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Other feature: " + feature["geometry"]["type"]);
                    break;
             }  
        }
    }

});
btn_process_geoman_layers.addTo(map).setPosition("bottomright");
```

Currently the data is all features of type `Polygon` from the Geoman plugin (a plugin used for drawing), which I want to post-process a little bit and perhaps insert into the PostGIS DB that my project is using.

Please note that I'm anything but seasoned web developer. In addition the code is quite messy since right now I am just trying to make things work. In the future the `switch` statement will probably be replaced by just the contents found inside `case "Polygon".

In my Django view I have the following endpoint (in my case this is `/`):

```
def view_map(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        request_feature = ... # Convert request.POST to a JSON or better GeoJSON object
        # Process feature

    # ...
```

My issue is that `request_feature` is a `QueryDict` and I cannot figure out how to convert it to a proper JSON/GeoJSON object in Python. An example would be:

```
<QueryDict: {'feature[type]': ['Feature'], 'feature[geometry][type]': ['Polygon'], 'feature[geometry][coordinates][0][0][]': ['8.408489', '48.934202'], 'feature[geometry][coordinates][0][1][]': ['8.408489', '48.96465'], 'feature[geometry][coordinates][0][2][]': ['8.467026', '48.96465'], 'feature[geometry][coordinates][0][3][]': ['8.467026', '48.934202'], 'feature[geometry][coordinates][0][4][]': ['8.408489', '48.934202']}>
```

Using `json.dumps(request.POST)` or `geojson.dumps(request.POST)` yields a JSON object but not in the form I am expecting it to be:

```
{ 
  "feature[type]": "Feature",
  "feature[geometry][type]": "Polygon",
  "feature[geometry][coordinates][0][0][]": "48.934202",
  "feature[geometry][coordinates][0][1][]": "48.96465",
  "feature[geometry][coordinates][0][2][]": "48.96465",
  "feature[geometry][coordinates][0][3][]": "48.934202",
  "feature[geometry][coordinates][0][4][]": "48.934202" 
}
```

So instead of e.g. calling `request_feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]` in Python to retrieve the array item, I have to do `request_feature['feature[geometry][coordinates][0]']`. Given how my data currently looks, I would say that I have a very flat dictionary-like object, where all initially nested objects are now at the top-level.

I am almost sure that I am doing something wrong on the Ajax side of things but I cannot pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can see some issues in your code. Lets start on how to [retrieve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) CSRF from cookies and how to [set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) the token on the AJAX request. Another problem is that you are sending a JavaScript object to your backend and not a JSON, because you are not [converting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your data.

Also, in your backend you should use request [`.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) to load the raw data (that comes in as bytes), then use json [`.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to deserialize it.

Here is a simple example using GeoJSON data structure presented at leafletjs [example documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/):

some_template.html

```
...
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        ...
    }

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    const feature = {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [[
                [-104.05, 48.99],
                [-97.22,  48.98],
                [-96.58,  45.94],
                [-104.03, 45.94],
                [-104.05, 48.99]
            ]]
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/map/json/',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        data: JSON.stringify(feature),
        success: function (res) { console.log(res);},
        dataType: "json"
    });
</script>
...
```

views.py

```
def map_json(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_feature = json.loads(request.body)
        print(request_feature)
        # Output
        # {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-104.05, 48.99],...]]}}

        print(request_feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0])
        # Output [-104.05, 48.99]

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'success'})
```

Comment: Oh, my...In my defense I did try with `JSON.stringify()` but given that all the rest is so broken, I guess that didn't really help much. Just one note: I did remove the contents of `url` since the IP is going to change at some point. This begs the question though why do you add `/json` to the URL? Is this a common practice? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I left the `URL` there just as an example, of course you want to point that to your own server. Regarding its path, its just how I wrote it at the moment of the answer to match the `view` name. But, since you asked about common practice, normally you have an exclusive view for this kind of `async` call and typically they only update parts of your page so maybe you want to be descriptive in your URL.